# Spring || JEE7?

Tags: java, spring, java-ee

Совсем запутался с Enterprise составляющей Java.

1. Правильно ли я понимаю, что JEE и Spring - такие штучки, что я могу взять одну из них и получить при том сразу сотни хороших(!) велосипедов? Т.е. многие вещи будут делаться в две строчки и быть безопасными, надёжными и тому подобное?
2. Нужен совет: а что учить в первую очередь? Очень не хочу услышать что-то в духе JEE учи, принципы поймёшь, потом берись за Spring, если это конечно не так в действительности, в чём я сомневаюсь.
   Вроде как можно взяться за Spring, начать понимать AOP (аспект-ориентированное программирование) и въезжать в инструменты конкретно Spring без изучения JEE. Достаточно отлично знать Java SE, знать основы сервлетов и пр.
3. Можно ли просто заниматься JEE и только с её помощью писать хорошие сетевые приложения? Реально ли сделать, к примеру, надёжный интернет магазин только с помощью JEE? Т.е. есть ли без Spring хорошая(!) жизнь?
4. В этом пункте укажите ваши наводки, как-то проясните мне ситуацию в голове.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java EE - это зонтичный стандарт, объединяющий в себе множество других стандартов. Входящие в него стандарты определяют принципы работы различных технологий, используемых при разработке корпоративных приложений. Например, JPA определяет как должен работать ORM, а Servlet определяет как должны обрабатываться сетевые запросы.

Spring - это зонтичный фреймворк, объединяющий в себе множество проектов, используемых при разработке корпоративных приложений. Например, Spring Core - это IoC-контейнер, а Spring MVC - фреймворк разработки web-приложений в рамках архитектуры MVC.

Важно понимать два момента: Во-первых, Java EE - это только стандарт и использовать его невозможно. Возможно использовать что-либо реализующее этот стандарт. Например, нельзя использовать JPA, можно использовать Hibernate или EclipseLink, а чтобы использовать сервлеты нужен контейнер сервлетов - Tomcat, Jetty, Undertow и т.п. Во-вторых, Spring использует Java EE. Spring MVC построен поверх сервлетов, а под капотом Spring Data прячется JPA. В теории можно использовать Spring, не зная Java EE, но только на очень поверхностном уровне,  стать профессиональным Spring разработчиком не получится.

А вот знать только Java EE, не зная Spring, возможно. Интернет-магазин вполне можно написать на JSF. Только зачем себя так ограничивать? JEE учи, принципы поймёшь, потом берись за Spring :)

Comment: Ахахаха, бесподобно! Спасибо :3

Answer (score 1):

Если вы не видели что такое Java EE, то можно посмотреть [здесь](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/overview/index.html).

> Java Platform, Enterprise Edition (Java EE) является стандартом в
>   программном обеспечении корпоративного сообщества. Java EE
>   разрабатывается с использованием Java Community Process с участием
>   отраслевых экспертов, коммерческих организаций с открытым исходным
>   кодом, групп пользователей Java и бесчисленных лиц. Каждый выпуск
>   объединяет новые функции, которые соответствуют потребностям отрасли,
>   улучшает переносимость приложений и повышает производительность
>   разработчиков.
>
> Сегодня Java EE предлагает богатую корпоративную программную платформу
>   и более [20 совместимых реализаций Java EE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/overview/compatibility-jsp-136984.html) на выбор.

Далее по списку можно посмотреть какие JSR входят или доступны на сервере приложений.

Можно конечно изучать все подряд, но сразу вы не сможете написать

> "сотни хороших(!) велосипедов"

поэтому порядок изучения состоит от простого к сложному.

[Spring](https://spring.io/) с другой стороны представляет собой фреймворк с открытым исходным кодом, что очень удобно использоавть для того чтобы понимать что происходит, когда вы решаете ту, или иную задачу.

Многое что дает Spring уже находится в Java EE, поэтому нет особой необходимости тащить его за собой. С другой стороны Spring предоставляет достаточно средств для создания полнофункциональных приложений.

Я думаю что для понимания Java нужно иметь представление и опыт работы в любом направлении. Поэтому изучение еще несколько фрейморков, которые не входят в Java EE и не являются частью Spring вам просто необходимо. Чем больше вы накопите знаний и опыта в различных фреймворках тем легче вам будет писать код, потому что фрейворки очень сильно облегчают жизнь разработчикам, ну правда может быть затрудняют ее архитекторам.

Comment: Извиняюсь, ответ мне не особо ясен. Я не собирался писать велосипеды, я спросил: правда ли, что в сути своей JEE&Spring -- 2 "фреймворка" навешивающие свои правила и дающие эти самые уже хорошо сделанные велосипеды.

Comment: по сути дела это так, только один свои правила публикует и стандартизирует, другой  - документирует.

Comment: Кто есть кто? Переоформите ответ, ответьте по пунктам, пожалуйста! Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Ответ дан как есть, не вижу возможности его улучшить, так что пожалуйста.