# Где можно практиковать JavaEE

Tags: java

Начал изучать JavaEE, но не знаю, где можно попрактиковать навыки.Мб вы знаете где можно посмотреть готовые проекты JavaEE или не готовые, что бы самому поделать и тд

Comment: изучайте алгоритмы и структуры данных, java ee на работе наедитесь =)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/843200/204920

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/819601/204920

Answer (score 4):

Во-первых, готовые проекты чего угодно на чём угодно можно посмотреть на GitHub.

Во-вторых, во многих учебниках разбираются учебные примеры. Часто в учебниках с первой по последнюю главу разрабатывается одно приложение постепенным усложнением кода.

Важно правильно работать с учебным кодом. Не запускать скачанный с сайта издательства код, а набирать его самостоятельно, после прочтения главы, и пытаться запустить. Если запуск не получается, то главу вы не поняли и её надо перечитать. После того, как запуск удался, можно сравнивать свой код с кодом автора. Стоит поэкспериментировать с кодом, внести в него несколько изменений, чтобы убедиться, что вы действительно понимаете, как он работает, а не просто успешно повторили заученные действия.

В-третьих, можно придумывать проекты самостоятельно. Полезно развивать креативность.

Comment: Добавлю, что при перепечатке кода из книжки полезно давать классам, методам и переменным свои собственные имена, а не копировать их из книжки. Во-первых, хорошая тренировка крайне полезного и необходимого навыка придумывать названия, а во-вторых, приходит понимание того, что в коде собственно твое, а что импортировано из какой-нибудь библиотеки.